# Constraint Anchors are not working well in Swift 4

Tags: swift, constraints, swift4

I cannot seem to figure out why there constraint anchors are not working

```
inputsContainerView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
inputsContainerView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
inputsContainerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -24).isActive = true
inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
```

I have tried looking everywhere but cannot seem to find the issue.

I do not see any conflicting constraints or warnings, basically I need the container to look like a white rectangle that sits in the center of the screen.

```
let inputsContainerView = UIView()
inputsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
inputsContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(inputsContainerView )
```

This is what it looks like:

[image: This is what it looks like]

This is what it should look like:

[image: This is what it should look like]

Comment: How are they not working?  What do you expect to happen and what is happening?  How is `inputsContainerView` created? Are you seeing any *conflicting constraints* warnings?

Comment: I do not see any conflicting constraints or warnings, basically I need the container to look like a white rectangle that sits in the center of the screen.

Comment: let inputsContainerView = UIView()
inputsContainerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
inputsContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
view.addSubview(inputsContainerView )

Comment: Edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: Why are you making the white rectangle `150` taller than the `view`?

Comment: Please take a look at it now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want your `inputsContainerView` to have a height of `150`.  Right now you are setting it equal to `view.height + 150`.

You need to set your `heightAnchor` equal to a constant:

Change this constraint:

```
inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor, constant: 150).isActive = true
```

to this:

```
inputsContainerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
```